# Move rows with inf to New matrix in R

Tags: r, row

So I have an NxN matrix, where some of the rows have inf for values.  What I want to do is move them to their own separate matrix.
Here is an example

```
 Matrix A
 1    3    9
 4    5    2
inf   6    7 
 0   inf   8
```

Remove rows with inf

```
 Matrix A
 1    3    9
 4    5    2

 Inf Matrix
inf   6    7 
 0   inf   8
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using standard subsetting and the function `is.infinite`:

```
##First create some data
m = matrix(1:12, ncol=3)
m[3,1] = Inf; m[4,2] = Inf
```

Then we calculate the condition on which to subset:

```
cond = apply(m, 1, function(i) any(is.infinite(i)))
```

Then subset as usual:

```
m[!cond,]
m[cond,]
```

Another way (but to me seems a bit more hacky) is to use row sums:

```
m[is.finitie(rowSums(m)),]
m[!is.finite(rowSums(m)),]
```

Not that if your matrix has `NA`, then these methods gives different results!

```
m[2,2] = NA
m[!is.finite(rowSums(m)),]
m[cond,]
```

Comment: Perhaps `is.finite(rowSums(m))` might seem a little less hacky.

Comment: @mnel Thanks. It occurred to me that the reason that it felt hacky was that it didn't handle `NA` nicely.

Answer (score 1):

since you are dealing with a matrix of numbers, `abs()` and `==` will be fast.

```
 # Logical Vector
 InfRows <- 0!=rowSums(abs(A) == Inf, na.rm=TRUE)

 InfMat  <- A[InfRows,  ]
 A.clean <- A[!InfRows, ]
```

---

#### Edit:  If you need to allow for NA's just use the `na.rm` argument in `rowSums()`

```
# same as above, but using na.rm
InfRows <- 0 != rowSums(abs(A) == Inf, na.rm=TRUE)
```

EXAMPLE:

```
  A[2:3, 2] <- NA
  A  
     # [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    3    9
# [2,]    4   NA    2
# [3,]  Inf   NA    7
# [4,]    0  Inf    8

InfRows <- 0 != rowSums(abs(A) == Inf, na.rm=TRUE)

InfMat  <- A[InfRows,  ]
A.clean <- A[!InfRows, ] 

InfMat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  Inf   NA    7
# [2,]    0  Inf    8

A.clean
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    3    9
# [2,]    4   NA    2
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if you had an `NA`, then the above method doesn't work.

Comment: @csgillespie, Thank you for bringing it up.  easily handled with `na.rm`.   Edited answer to reflect.

Comment: I always forget about `na.rm`. Could catch +1